# How do I make a response email be from the person submitting (Google App Script)

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I have a Google form which submits to a spreadsheet. I then have written this code which sends an email with the results. Can anyone tell me how I make the email be submitted by the person who submitted the form?

function Initialize() {

```
var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();

for (var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}

ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendConfirmationMail")
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
```

}
function SendConfirmationMail(e) {

```
try {
    var ss, cc, subject, columns;
    var message, value, textbody, sendername, sender;

    // This is my email address and I will be in the CC
    cc = e.namedValues["Username"].toString();

    // This will show up as the sender's name
    sendername = e.namedValues["Name"].toString();

    subject = "Ticket Submitted";

    message = "We have received your details.<br>Thanks!<br><br>";

    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    columns = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    // This is the submitter's email address
    sender = e.namedValues["Username"].toString();

    // Only include form values that are not blank
    for ( var keys in columns ) {
        var key = columns[keys];
        if ( e.namedValues[key] ) {
            message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "<br />"; 
        }
    }
    textbody = message.replace("<br>", "\n");
    GmailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, textbody, 
                        {cc: cc, name: sendername, htmlBody: message});
} catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, nor it should be. You want to impersonate someone else without their consent.

The archaic email system unfortunately allows that, therefore making easier the life of spammers and phishing scams. But Google and other Internet companies work hard to prevent and filter this kind of emails.

Bottom line, you will not be able to send an email as somebody else from a Google app unless it's an authorized account in your Gmail.

The best you can do is set the `reply-to` address.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I want to set the form up so that when someone submits it, its from their email address.

Comment: No, I have not misunderstood you. You want that the "from address" of the email you send (using the script) is of who have sent the form, and that is exactly what I've answered.

Comment: But if the form adds the 'from' address to the form by default, and I receive their address as part of the form, how is that different in Google's eyes? I'm still receiving their email address regardless. I'm trying to make the form submit a ticket to Assembla.com which will take their email address so that replies may be sent to them. It's legit, and we use Gmail as a client so the only people who would have access to the form would be employees. There's no way I can do this without writing a Java app which basically does exactly this?

Comment: It is one thing to know someone else's email, and another one the be able to send emails as them. Also, it is not relevant if your use-case is "legit", this "impersonating" capability is wrong. But if you're inside a Google Apps domain (explained just now by your receiving addresses by default), and you are the domain admin, then you can impersonate **your domain** users. Look it up, and if you have doubts please post another question mentioning that and your specific problem.